# How can I squeezing a Capsule while animation is active in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a Capsule which change it`s position on screen I want to make the Capsule get squeezed on both ends, but the animation does not allow me to do this, because it takes 2 View as start and end, and I just could manage left and right changing effect, so there is no room for squeezed effect to work! How can I do this as well? like apple done it.

[image]

[image]

```
struct CapsuleView: View {

    @State private var startAnimation: Bool = Bool()

    var body: some View {

        return Capsule()
            .fill(Color.secondary)
            .frame(height: 5, alignment: .center)
            .overlay(Capsule().fill(Color.green).frame(width: 100.0, height: 5, alignment: Alignment.center), alignment: startAnimation ? Alignment.trailing : Alignment.leading)
            .onAppear() { startAnimation.toggle() }
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: startAnimation)

    }

}
```

Comment: Can't you just imagine the green capsule as being "behind" and going much further on the right and on the left ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty code, but based on @Zaphod`s proposal try using a mask and put your capsule behind it. then animate the offset based on the frame sizes

```
struct SnakeLoading: View {
    @State
    private var animating: Bool = true
    
    private let height: CGFloat = 10
    private let capsuleWidth: CGFloat = 100
    
    func leadingOffset(size: CGSize) -> CGFloat {
        (-size.width - capsuleWidth) * 0.5 + height
    }
    
    func trailingOffset(size: CGSize) -> CGFloat {
        (size.width + capsuleWidth) * 0.5 - height
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack {
                // Background
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.gray)
                // Capsule
                Capsule()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .offset(x: animating ? leadingOffset(size: geo.size) : trailingOffset(size: geo.size))
                    .frame(width: capsuleWidth, height: height)
                    .onAppear() { animating.toggle() }
                    .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: animating)

            }
            .mask(Capsule()
                    .frame(height: height)
            )
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is good way but I noticed my code and your code as well get problem on orientation change.

Comment: yeah I feared that might happen, as I stated: quick and dirty ;)

Comment: I would be happy if you fix orientation issue as well if you find a way, thanks

Comment: I'll give it a try asap :)